# Probability, change of variable

Tags: probability, change-of-variable

[image]

I have figured out that the Jacobian is r using trig identities. But why is the exponent divided by two? And where is the 1/2pi. Here is what I have done so far :

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct, I think there is a mistake in the task, and it should be $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{- \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks! I have been sitting before this for some hours now.....

Comment: You are asked to find the marginal density of $R$ from the joint density you obtained.

Comment: I totally did not get that.... i should read more carefully many thanks!